# How to get time range in a log file in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed, grep

I want to get an interval of one hour in my log file. Here's a sample log:

```
2016-03-30|00:54:46,060|[WARNING]
2016-03-30|00:55:46,318|[OK]
2016-03-30|00:55:46,318|[OK]
2016-03-30|01:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|01:53:16,356|[CRITICAL]
2016-03-30|02:56:41,410|[WARNING]
2016-03-30|02:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|02:53:16,356|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|03:56:41,410|[WARNING]
```

I define some variables: `date_now=date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N"`, `date_minus_one=date -d "-1 hour" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N"` and `date_minus_two=date -d "-2 hour" +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N"`. I know the logic that you can get a per hour by making `date_now >= date_minus_one and date_now <= date_minus_two. But I don't know how can I make that in awk, sed or grep.

I want the output result will be:

```
2016-03-30|02:56:41,410|[WARNING]
2016-03-30|02:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|02:53:16,356|[UNKNOWN]
```

So on and so forth to get a 1 hour interval of logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#To get the current date and hour



  hour=$( date +'%F|%H')


#Filter the logs 

grep $hour log
```

Note: Edited Based on suggestion in comment.

Comment: That's a [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) and an absurd contortion to get `date +'%F|%h'`

Comment: thanks for efficent way, I have incorporated your suggestions. however, earlier version was also providing users solution.

Comment: The Awk is still superfluous; `date +%H` obtains the current hour. (Sorry for the case error before.)

Comment: awesome, thanks you.!

Answer (score 1):

Using `grep`:

```
grep -E '^2016-03-30\|02:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2},' file.log
```

From a variable:

```
hour_to_search=$(date '+%F\|%H') 
grep -E "^${hour_to_search}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}," file.log
```

Or use a speciic date-time as reference:

```
hour_to_search=$(date -d '30 Mar 2016 02 AM' '+%F\|%H')
grep -E "^${hour_to_search}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}," file.log
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.log
2016-03-30|00:54:46,060|[WARNING]
2016-03-30|00:55:46,318|[OK]
2016-03-30|00:55:46,318|[OK]
2016-03-30|01:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|01:53:16,356|[CRITICAL]
2016-03-30|02:56:41,410|[WARNING]
2016-03-30|02:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|02:53:16,356|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|03:56:41,410|[WARNING]

$ hour_to_search=$(date -d '30 Mar 2016 02 AM' '+%F\|%H') 

$ echo "$hour_to_search"                                  
2016-03-30\|02

$ grep -E "^${hour_to_search}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}," file.txt
2016-03-30|02:56:41,410|[WARNING]
2016-03-30|02:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
2016-03-30|02:53:16,356|[UNKNOWN]
```

Comment: How can i make it dynamic? that every hour I can get the data. No need to enter values of date and hour. Thanks,

Comment: @RobertJohnMartin Check my edits..

Comment: This approach has the same shortcoming as Michael's answer of being "aligned" on hours of the actual time, so in the worst case there will be almost no output because the hour you are grepping for has just started.

Comment: @heemayl : how about the hour? how can you make it dynamic? I've tried your syntax it works but I need to change the hour to get the past one hour data.

Comment: Nicely done. You can probably assume that after `2016-03-30|02` the format will be consistent and just grep for this part.

Answer (score 0):

Make search pattern that includes the date and hour only (`"%Y-%m-%d|%H:"`) and use it for filtering with any one of the tools you've mentioned

Comment: I've tried awk: `awk '$date_file >= $date_minus_one && $date_file <= $date_minus_two` but it always print all the data.

Comment: I suggested `DATE_PATTERN=$( date +"%Y-%m-%d|%H:"); grep $DATE_PATTERN `

Comment: This approach will cause the output to be "aligned" on hours, so in the worst case you will get less than one minute of output, because the last hour has just started.

Comment: Yes, but this is exactly what was the purpose of this question: "I want to get an interval of one hour"

Comment: @Michael: (Edit:) Actually I think it's not really clear, the OP could have meant it both ways.

Comment: I do not see another option in this question but I do not want to argue. There are too many ways such an issue can be asked and answered.

Comment: Yes, I want to get data an hour from the past everytime I execute my script. For example I run a crontab job that executes my script per hour and the file output that I want is the data from the past one hour.

Comment: @Robert In this case my answer is good enough. Just form the pattern that meets that last hour.

Comment: @Michael Now I get it I should run my cron 58 or 59 minutes before it become another hour to get 00 to 58 minutes of data. Am I correct?

Comment: Why? This will give you the pattern from the previous hour: `PREV_HOUR=$(date +"%H") ; PREV_HOUR=$(expr $PREV_HOUR - 1) ; DATE_STRING=$( date +"%Y-%m-%d"); DATE_STRING="$DATE_STRING|$PREV_HOUR"` You can optimize it, of course

Answer (score 0):

You might also try something like

```
csplit -zk sample.log '/2016-03-30|0'{0..9}/ '{*}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to this

```
awk -F "|" '{ print "date -d\""$1 " " $2"\" +%s.%N" "'\''|" $0 "'\''" }' mylog.file  |\
  bash |\
  awk -F "|" -v OFS="|" \
    -v startdate=$(date -d "2016-03-30 01:42:13,691" "+%s.%N") \
    -v enddate=$(date -d "2016-03-30 02:53:16,356" "+%s.%N") \
    '$1>=startdate && $1<=enddate {$1="";print}'
```

Adapt the `startdate` and `enddate` to your needs, it should be seconds since EPCOH and nanoseconds: format is `"+%s.%N"`

First part with `awk ...` just build a `date` command line and uses `bash` to execute it. The goal is to add at the beginning of each line the date as seconds since EPOCH and nanoseconds.

The final `awk` compares the dates in seconds.nanoseconds format and prints only the lines in the range: `[startdate .. enddate]`

The test:

```
$ awk -F "|" \
  '{ print "date -d\""$1 " " $2"\" +%s.%N" "'\''|" $0 "'\''" }' mylog.file  |\
  bash |\
  awk -F "|" -v OFS="|" \
    -v startdate=$(date -d "2016-03-30 01:42:13,691" "+%s.%N") \
    -v enddate=$(date -d "2016-03-30 02:53:16,356" "+%s.%N") \
    '$1>=startdate && $1<=enddate {$1="";print}'

|2016-03-30|01:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
|2016-03-30|01:53:16,356|[CRITICAL]
|2016-03-30|02:42:13,691|[UNKNOWN]
|2016-03-30|02:53:16,356|[UNKNOWN]
```